# Titled frame panel for GWT (using FIELDSET and LEGEND html tags)

Tags: html, gwt, event-handling, fieldset, legend

I'm trying to create a titled border frame in GWT, which results in this:

[image: Legend+Fieldset]

This can be done using HTML fieldset and legend tags, such as

```
<fieldset> 
    <legend>Connection parameters</legend>
    ... the rest ...
</fieldset>
```

I want to create a custom widget in GWT that implements that. I managed to do that, but the problem is that events that happen inside the widget (button click etc) does not get fired although I have added the handler.

My implementation of the widget is as follows:

```
public class TitledPanel extends Widget {
private Element legend;
private Widget content = null;

public TitledPanel() {
    Element fieldset = DOM.createFieldSet();
    legend = DOM.createLegend();
    DOM.appendChild(fieldset, legend);
    setElement(fieldset);
}

public TitledPanel(String title) {
    this();
    setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return DOM.getInnerHTML(legend);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(String html) {
    DOM.setInnerHTML(legend, html);
}

public Widget getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(Widget content) {
    if (this.content != null) {
        DOM.removeChild(getElement(), this.content.getElement());
    }

    this.content = content;

    DOM.appendChild(getElement(), content.getElement());
}
}
```

Do I need to extend Composite, or need to manually reroute the events, or is there other ways?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for [CaptionPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CaptionPanel.html):

> A panel that wraps its contents in a border with a caption that appears in the upper left corner of the border. This is an implementation of the fieldset HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you just call `DOM.appendChild` - this doesn't cause the `TitledPanel` to adopt the `Widget`. The normal course of action is that you extend `Composite` and then call `initWidget(Widget widget)` - inside the hood it calls `widget.setParent(this);`, which in turn makes the parent adopt this widget and attach it to the browser's document. However com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget) is only package-visible so you can't call it from your code (after, for example, `DOM.appendChild`).

I'd recommend reading [Widget Best Practices / Widget Building](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/05/widget-best-practices-widget-building.html), especially the **Clean up after yourself** and/or look at the source code for some GWT Widgets, to get the idea how the GWT sees custom widget creation.

And, as Robert [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523997/titled-frame-panel-for-gwt-using-fieldset-and-legend-html-tags/1524807#1524807), CaptionPanel is the safer route :)